# Distance from point or edge when using ST_ClusterWithin with polygons

Tags: postgis

When using `ST_ClusterWithin` with polygons, is the distance calculated from the polygon's centroid or it's edges?

This information is absent from [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually distances between shapes are measured as the shortest distance.

It is trivial to validate it:

```
WITH testdata AS
  (SELECT unnest(ARRAY['POLYGON ((5 5, 7 5, 7 7, 5 7, 5 5))'::geometry,
               'POLYGON ((0 0, 4 0, 4 4, 0 4, 0 0))'::geometry]) AS geom)
SELECT ST_AsText(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 1.42))) FROM testdata;
```

--> returns 1 row

The centroids (2;2) and (6;6) are 5.6 units away. The closest points (4;4) and (5;5) are 1.41 units away.

Since a single cluster was created using a distance of 1.42, it confirms the shortest distance between shapes is considered.